# Reload page on orientationchange only when landscape > 1024px

Tags: reload, tablet, orientation-changes

I need to target a tablet only when the landscape mode is bigger than 1024px and reload on orientation change.Reload everytime I change orientation.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
      if (($(window).width() > 1024)  && ($(window).height() > 1024)){ 
        location.reload(); 
      }
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
if (($(window).width() > 1024)  || ($(window).height() >= 1024)){   
        $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
             location.reload(); 
        });   
}
```